# Unable to install libevent-devel

Tags: libevent

I'm trying to install **libevent-devel** but it failed due to dependencies which shown below.

I tried also to install the dependencies needed by libevent-devel but it also failed as its needs the libevent-devel as shown below.

How can I resolved this issue?hope for your helped.

[root@box1 opt]# rpm -ivh libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.x86_64.rpm

warning: libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:

```
libevent-doc = 1.4.13-4.el6 is needed by libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.x86_64
libevent-headers = 1.4.13-4.el6 is needed by libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.x86_64
```

[root@box1 opt]#

[root@box1 opt]# rpm -ivh libevent-doc-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch.rpm

warning: libevent-doc-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:

```
libevent-devel = 1.4.13-4.el6 is needed by libevent-doc-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch
```

[root@box1 opt]#

[root@box1 opt]# rpm -ivh libevent-headers-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch.rpm

warning: libevent-headers-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:

```
libevent-devel = 1.4.13-4.el6 is needed by libevent-headers-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch
```

[root@box1 opt]#

Answer (score 4):

Download the libevent package from http://libevent.org/ and compile it.

```
wget "https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-1.4.14b-stable.tar.gz"
tar -xzvf libevent-1.4.14b-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-1.4.14b-stable
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `rpm` *all* the mutually dependent packages on the same command line, and it will recognize that the dependencies are satisfied:

```
rpm -ivh libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.x86_64.rpm libevent-doc-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch.rpm libevent-headers-1.4.13-4.el6.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this circular dependency.
Just workaround it by using the --nodeps option.

```
[root@box1 opt]# rpm -ivh libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.x86_64.rpm --nodeps
```

Once installed, you can now install libevent-doc and libevent-headers without problems.